# sql query to combine two table whose row data should not exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `mysql` database. I have three tables carts,courses and checks. I need a row of data which combines carts and courses tables and should not exist in checks table, and I am passing `userid = $id` from my php function. Here the userid is same for both the table.

```
Courses table:
id | name    |
1  | PMP     |
2  | CAPM    |
3  | Prince2 |


Carts table:

    id |userid | username | orderid             | exam_id |
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 1       |
    2  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 2       |
    3  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 3       |
    4  |14     | Rakesh   |678g310v671N888M6720 | 3       |

checks table :

    id |userid | username | orderid             | exam_id |
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 1       |
    2  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 2       |
```

so I need a output which combines carts and courses table but the data should not exist in checks table and i am passing userid = $id from my php function:

```
1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | Prince2  |
2  |14     | Rakesh   |678g310v671N888M6720 | Prince2  |
```

Comment: you should try using JOIN query between Carts and Courses. try it yourself and if you still can't figure it out then tell us your query and we'll try to correct it

Answer (score 0):

I free-typed this, but it should give you a solid place to start:

```
SELECT cT.UserID, cT.UserName, cT.OrderID, cS.Name
FROM Carts cT #Carts appears to be the 'base' from which your query originates
INNER JOIN Courses cS ON cT.Exam_ID = cS.ID #Require both Carts & Courses
LEFT JOIN Checks cK ON cT.OrderID = cK.OrderID #Optionally rq Checks
WHERE cK.OrderID IS NULL #but only where there is no check
```

Comment: Actually there is a "status" column in carts table and i want to take status = 'Completed' and userid = $id from the php function so how can i include this with the Jenni's sql query

Comment: I have written like this but it showing all the user's data select c.userid, c.username,c.date,c.venue,c.price,c.noOf_orders,c.amount, c.order_id,c.status cS.name
FROM carts c INNER JOIN courses cS ON c.exam_id = cS.id LEFT JOIN checks cK ON c.order_id = cK.order_id AND c.status ='Completed' AND c.userid = '$id'

Comment: A LEFT join assumes you want all of the data from the first column, then choose data from the second column based on the ON criteria. If you want to filter data in the first, that will go into your WHERE clause.